# how to update products from frontend side in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, frontend

I need to update product from frontend side.so, is there any possibility  to update products from frontend side in magento2 ?

Comment: By using any script or form ?

Comment: On listing page or detail page? Where u want to update? Give more details

Comment: I have developed a custom tool in which we customize products and view all the edited products on both sides. and if i click on edit in tool we need to update the products after clicking on save button

Comment: products can be multiple @AnkitShah